# How to get field Name from Map

Tags: apex, xml

I am trying to map CSV file with Salesforce Account field using XML. I am getting Account field from Map. But when i use the name i am getting error.

```
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SOBJECT:Account].(String)
```

My code :

```
xmlMap = new Map<String, String>();   
    for(Dom.XMLNode child : SalesforceObjecet.getChildElements()) {           
            objecetName = child.getText();
            system.debug('Object Name in XML field  ' + objecetName );

            for(Dom.XMLNode subchild : child.getChildElements()) 
            {
                system.debug('Sub child node ' + subchild.getNodeType() );
                Dom.XmlNode[] childnodes = subchild.getChildElements();
                System.debug('Child nodes are ' + childnodes[0].getText()) ;
                System.debug('Child nodes are ' + childnodes[1].getText()) ;                    

                xmlMap.put(childnodes[1].getText(), childnodes[0].getText());
                system.debug('Xml map view : ' + xmlMap);
            }
   } 

   for(integer i = 0; i < filedvalueClone.size(); i++){

         if(xmlMap.containskey(filedvalueClone[i]))
         { 
           system.debug('csv field Value in loop ' + filedvalueClone[i]);
           system.debug('if contains in map ' + xmlMap.containskey(filedvalueClone[i]));
           system.debug('Size of the file value ' + fileValues.size()); 

           for(integer j = 1; j < fileValues.size(); j++){
           //system.debug('size of j ' + j);     
                    system.debug('Creating Account ');
                    system.debug('Field Name ' + filedvalueClone[i] );
                    system.debug('Field Name values ' + fileValues[j][i] );
                    system.debug('Get Map value ' + xmlMap.get(filedvalueClone[i]) );
                    Account a = new Account();
                    a.(xmlMap.get(filedvalueClone[i]))= fileValues[i][j];
                    acLst.add(a);
            }
         }
    }
```

Please guide me how to use the field name from map for insert. Is it possible to do.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you instantiating the map?

Comment: yes i have added the code where map get populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a concrete object `Account` and assign a value to a field referenced by a string. In order to do that you will need to cast the account to a sObject and use `sObject.put('FieldName', value);`.

In your case it would be

```
sObject a = new Account();
a.put(xmlMap.get(filedvalueClone[i]), fileValues[i][j]);
acLst.add((Account)a);
```

I haven't tested this but that is the whole concept behind it.

For more information visit the following links:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SObjects.htm

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm